# Sitecore Commerce - Unable to save Address

Tags: sitecore-commerce

**Sitecore Commerce 9.3**

We are using the Address Editor component to store the users' addresses for account management. But logged in uses are not able to save addresses.

[image]

**Getting this error in console on click on Save changes:** `/api/cxa/AccountAddress/AddressEditorModify`

> Errors: Address could not be added.

[image]

Getting these errors in logs, (not sure if they are related):

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: {
  "Message": "Operation failed: One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionMessage": "One or more dependencies failed",
  "ExceptionType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.DependencyFailedException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Store Error: Login failed for user '<projectName>_collectionuser'.. The error occurred while attempting to perform the underlying storage operation during 'Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.ShardManagement.StoreException: Error occurred while performing store operation

Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Get[TEntity](IXdbContext context, IEntityReference`1 reference, ExpandOptions expandOptions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.LoadNonObsoleteContact(IXdbContext xdbContext, IEntityReference`1 contactReference, ExpandOptions expandOptions)
  

Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
```

Comment: Seems like xDB issue, please check if your license is valid for xconnect and xconnect is working

Comment: Thanks for the reply @GauravAgarwal. I've checked the licence, it is valid for xconnect and xconnect is working fine.

Comment: can you see any error in Authoring logs?

Comment: Yep, getting this error there: ERROR PipelineAbort:Customers.block.CreateCustomerAddress: Address  for Customer Entity-Customer-c1053debb7944b71b7a39e5939216e48 is not valid.

Comment: Try to pass CA in state and test please, because we got stateCode issue sometime

Comment: yeah, even i was thinking the same and tried with state code, but no luck. Even I tried entering some numbers for state codes. Getting the same error in authoring logs. 00105 06:04:16 WARN CtxMsg.ValidationError.InvalidOrMissingPropertyValue: Text=Invalid or missing value for property ' StateCode'. Should be in the range ' 1 - 20' .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130466/discussion-between-gaurav-agarwal-and-raman-gupta).